# SQL - Grouping by ID is not giving unique results

Tags: sql, ssms, grouping

I have a table which contains various IDs tied to amounts.

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 134.78 |
| 1005 | 78.90 |
| 1003 | 54.00 |
| 1005 | -40.00 |
| 1001 | 134.78 |

I want to effectively 'pivot' this data and have one line per ID with the sum of the amount column next to it.

```
select ID, SUM(Amount) as 'Revenue'
from REVENUE
where id is not null
group by id, Amount;
```

I've written the query above but many IDs are being shown twice/three times with a partial sum next to each one. How can I force SQL to ensure one line per ID?

Example results I'm receiving below:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 6347 | -142.86 |
| 8103 | -338.00 |
| 8115 | -507.00 |
| 6347 | 4.29 |
| 6367 | 9.10 |
| 8103 | 416.00 |
| 8115 | 279.50 |
| 8103 | 832.00 |
| 8115 | 559.00 |
| 8103 | 4160.00 |
| 8115 | 2795.00 |
| 6347 | 432.40 |
| 6367 | 918.86 |

Expecting:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 6347 | 1208.4 |
| 8103 | 5070 |

Comment: Why are you *grouping* **and** *aggregating* on the column `Amount`? The query is working exactly as expected; one row per *distinct* value of `ID` and `Amount`.

Comment: Change `group by id, Amount;` to `group by id;`

Comment: Remove Amount from group-by - but surely you would have experimented with this?

Comment: Yes, I added 'Amount' into group, whilst experimenting. The results are still off and not unique.

Comment: Hi - it would be helpful if you edited your question to show sample data, the actual query you are running, the result you are getting and the result you want. At the moment your initial dataset doesn’t relate to either of the outputs and your code is “experimental” - all of which makes it difficult for anyone to help you. What’s the datatype for ID? If it’s a text datatype do you have additional spaces and/or non-printing characters in your values?

Comment: If you do just `group by id` then you will get a single row for every id. It is that simple

Answer (score 0):

you can group the sql only by id rather than combination of id, amount to get the
desired results

```
select ID, SUM(Amount) as 'Revenue'
from REVENUE
where id is not null
group by id;
```