# How can l group row data by date using window function?

Tags: sql-server-2014-localdb

In my code below the row data are not grouping into month by month name. I want to group row data of the same month.

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | 500 |
| 2023-03-29 | 300 |
| 2023-04-15 | 600 |
| 2023-05-11 | 300 |
| 2023-05-23 | 600 |
| 2023-05-31 | 500 |

```
SELECT  
    DATENAME(month, OrderDate) as Month,
        Sum(Amount) as revenue,
        Amount - LAG (Amount) OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate ASC) AS Revenue_growth       
FROM OrderDetail
Group by OrderDate
```

Expected output

| Date | Revenue | Revenue_growth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| March | 800 | 0 |
| April | 600 | -200 |
| May | 1400 | 800 |

Comment: Why are you *grouping* **and** `SUM`ing on the same column? If you `GROUP BY` the column `Amount` and `OrderDate` you get one row per distinct value of `OrderDate` and `Amount`.

Comment: Huh, I *did* [literally ask someone this 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76541779/sql-grouping-by-id-is-not-giving-unique-results#comment134955751_76541779).

Comment: @ThomA  if l don't group OrderDate and Amount it produces an error that a group clause should be applied. Can you show  me an alternative way?